# phpCurl request field miss?

Tags: php, post, curl, libcurl

My PHP code run with response : parameter--"token" missing, I don't know why , I'm quite sure that token is correct.

Sample Image:
[image: Sample Image]

```
<?php
{
    $url = "http://r.catchoom.com/v1/search";

    $queryimg = "saestor://image/2222.jpg";

    $token="5fb568dc8b5041b1";

    $post_data = array ('token' =>"5fb568dc8b5041b1;type=text/plain",'image' =>"@$queryImg;type=image/jpeg");

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    //curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,  array('Content-type: multipart/form-data;charset=UTF-8'));

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_data);

    $result =curl_exec($ch);

    curl_close($ch);

    var_dump($result);
}
```

Comment: That looks like a response from the service you're posting to.  You probably need to check their documentation or allowed methods.  I'm not sure it has anything to do with your code.  Do you have any documentation or anything like that to help move this question forward?

Comment: http://catchoom.com/documentation/api/recognition/

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the filetype specifier from the `$post_data` for the token key value pair.  The filetype should only be used when you're posting a file.

`$post_data = array ('token' =>"5fb568dc8b5041b1",'image' =>"@$queryImg;type=image/jpeg");`

Also, according to PHP's documentation for cURL.  Posting a file in the POSTFIELDS has been deprecated and should be done by using the [curl_file_create( )](https://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-file-create.php) function.

Given those pieces of information, you should try the following:

```
$queryimg = "saestor://image/2222.jpg";
$token= "5fb568dc8b5041b1";
$image_to_post = curl_file_create($queryimg, 'image/jpeg', '2222.jpg');
$post_data = array ('token' => $token, 'image' => $image_to_post);
```

For versions of PHP < 5.5, you can use the code below to recreate the functionality of `curl_file_create( )` which is an alias for the `cURLFile` constructor.

```
if (!function_exists('curl_file_create')) {
    function curl_file_create($filename, $mimetype = '', $postname = '') {
        return "@$filename;filename="
            . ($postname ?: basename($filename))
            . ($mimetype ? ";type=$mimetype" : '');
    }
}
```

If you're still having problems getting your solution to work, I would just use the [PHP SDK](https://github.com/Catchoom/catchoom-php) Catchoom has developed.  It's hard to go wrong with an SDK!  They even include an [example](https://github.com/Catchoom/catchoom-php/blob/master/example.php).

Comment: My php environment is PHP-5.3.x,maybe not support CurlFile ?

Comment: I have removed filetype but it still return "Token is missing"

Comment: I've updated my answer to include a fix for versions of PHP < 5.5 and also made a few suggestions.  Good luck!

Comment: Still failed... so sad, I do as PHP SDK but response with token missing, I doubt that whether my sever PHP environment charset influence token's charset ? I have try to use sniffer like httpfox to grab post data but get nothing.